# Как выровнять блоки относительно друг друга при разной высоте контента?

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Как исправить проблему с кривыми блоками секций из-за количества символов в тексте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```css
.features {
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}

.features .title {
  font-size: 2.4em;
}

.JeggyBotAvatar {
  width: 200px
}

.features h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-property: all;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #25252e;
  padding-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}

.wrapper-1:hover {
  background-color: #2c2d40;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.wrapper-1 p {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper-1">
  <h1>Настройки</h1>
  <p>У бота есть множество важных настроек для Вашего сервера.</p>
</section>
<section class="wrapper-1">
  <h1>Мини-игры</h1>
  <p>В боте есть несколько мини-игр, с которыми Вы не заскучаете!</p>
</section>
<section class="wrapper-1">
  <h1>Система логов</h1>
  <p>Вы можете включить функцию логирования действий на сервере через Джегги.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: ты создаешь 3 разные секции а должен создать одну с 3 блоками, у секции задай `width: 100%` а у блоков уже столько сколько хочешь взависимости от разрешения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно добавить обертку для блоков `section` и воспользоваться, например, [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex) что бы блоки выровнялись относительно верхнего края:

```
.section-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Рабочий пример:

```css
.section-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.features {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 20px 60px 20px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.features .title {
  font-size: 2.4em;
}

.JeggyBotAvatar {
  width: 200px
}

.features h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper-1 {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #25252e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-property: all;
}

.wrapper-1:hover {
  background-color: #2c2d40;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.wrapper-1 p {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <section class="wrapper-1">
    <h1>Настройки</h1>
    <p>У бота есть множество важных настроек для Вашего сервера.</p>
  </section>
  <section class="wrapper-1">
    <h1>Мини-игры</h1>
    <p>В боте есть несколько мини-игр, с которыми Вы не заскучаете!</p>
  </section>
  <section class="wrapper-1">
    <h1>Система логов</h1>
    <p>Вы можете включить функцию логирования действий на сервере через Джегги.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

нужен родитель для блоков `<section class="wrapper-1">`
и ему уже прописывать flex, [руководство по flex'ам:](https://tpverstak.ru/flex-cheatsheet/)